# What are good tools for automatically crawling websites, check for certain links, and extract data?

Tags: web-browser, scraping

I would like to automatically crawl about 1 million URLs (on a CSV file) and check whether the sites provide a Facebook Login button (i.e., users can create accounts by connecting their Facebook account to the site). Then, I would like to record for which sites these buttons were found.

I would also like to check whether the site uses HTTPS and makes use of cookies.

What are good tools?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest [python](http://python.org) possibly plus the [scrapy](http://scrapy.org) library.

- Free & Open Source
- Python comes with a CSV library so you can quickly read and parse your csv file
- Python has several url and web access libraries that can do what you need
- Scapy simplifies getting and parsing the web pages.

Comment: much as I dislike "code it yourself answers" http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/1201/is-source-code-an-acceptable-answer I have to agree that there is unlikely to be a tool which does what the OP wants. However, if he is looking for a programming solution then he should be asking on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/  An interesting question, though.

Comment: OP, if you are not a coder and you can spare $168, you might want to look at http://www.fminer.com/

Comment: Or, you might pay someone to develop it cheaply, as it is relatively simple. See https://www.fiverr.com/categories/programming-tech and similar

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion, guys. I will try out scrapy/python first.

Comment: Of course, if you can code Python, then, in addition to scrapy, there is also Beautiful Soup  http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/   You can google for comparisons. Thee is a pretty good comparison at http://www.quora.com/How-do-I-determine-between-using-Beautiful-Soup-or-Scrapy  Bottom line, "
Scrapy has steeper learning curve than Beautiful Soup, but it does have more features. Beautiful Soup can be limited by your designated URL unless you set up an infinite loop providing certain criteria manually".

Comment: Or if you don't already code in python you will find that you can get started very quickly - look out though - it can be addictive.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to crawl certain website for links, you may try [sitechecker web crawler](https://sitechecker.pro/website-crawler/) or [screaming frog](https://www.screamingfrog.co.uk/seo-spider/). They have a convenient interface and many useful functions:
1) website monitoring
2) detecting certain URLs
3) explore internal links and their anchors